# Getting a "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 when running my FOAM website

Tags: javascript

Trying to run my foam website through the demo and I'm getting a **404**. It is looking for a `favicon.ico` that I never defined.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Please, provide code and error or upload it to somewhere and share the link. You can use codepen.io

Comment: i'm trying to run the tutorial - http://foam-framework.github.io/foam/tutorial/phonecat/0-intro/ -, so i can add a link to that .. i downloaded a random favicon.ico file and it loads. It'd be better if it skipped the lookup though.

Comment: Browsers will try to find `favicon.ico` in the root of your website, unless you specify it's somewhere else using Meta tags.  Basically unless you want a favicon, and are happy to use the browsers default, you can ignore this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<domain.com>/favicon.ico` is automatically loaded by the browser. It's the little icon that shows up next to the title in your open tabs and bookmarks. Try opening https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico for an example. Nothing in the code tells the browser to look for this; the browser just does it.

> Notice how as of writing, that link redirects the url to a `cdn.sstatic.net` link. This means the browser shows you the `favicon.ico` file for Stack Overflow as requested, but then the tab itself shows https://cdn.sstatic.net/favicon.ico, which is the Stack *Exchange* icon. Screenshot provided for historical purposes.

[image: Screenshot]